# Converting seconds to HH:MM:SS in SSRS using function

Tags: function, reporting-services, time, ssrs-2012, date-conversion

I had a function below that was working to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS in SSRS. This needs to work for seconds in excess of 86400 i.e. the total time could be greater than 24 hours. This function below is now returning strange values like 00:00:.2 or 00:00:75

```
Public Function ConvertSecondsToHourMinSec(ByVal intTotalSeconds) As String
Dim hours As String =INT(intTotalSeconds/3600)
If Len(hours) < 2 Then
    hours = RIGHT(("0" & hours), 2)
End If
Dim mins As String = RIGHT("0" & INT((intTotalSeconds MOD 3600)/60), 2)
Dim secs AS String = RIGHT("0" & ((intTotalSeconds MOD 3600) MOD 60), 2)

ConvertSecondsToHourMinSec = hours & ":" & mins & ":" & secs

End Function
```

Passing this function a value of 227.16666 gives 00:03:67, for example.

Any idea how I can fix this function to properly give HH:MM:SS?

Answer (score 0):

Realized I wasn't converting the seconds to INT on the bottom. Works good now.